# Do cronjob run when the computer is asleep?

Tags: terminal, sleep-wake

I have a macbook air running El Capitan. I wrote a few cronjob that appear to be running even when the computer is asleep.

Is this correct, or is my computer not really in a sleep state?

Comment: In System Preferences > Energy Saver, check to see if Enable Power Nap is checked. If it is checked, this might be the reason, but I have no definitive source for this assertion.

Comment: Are you certain it is not run as it awakes? i.e. it wakes, detects the job is overdue, then runs it.

Comment: @John2095, no because I write the time to a log when it runs, and it definitely runs a few times at night when I put my computer to sleep. It seems to not do it EVERY time, but I find in the logs that sometimes runs while asleep. Maybe the computer wakes sometimes on power nap to do other tasks and this get run incidentally?

Comment: @IconDaemon, I tested that by writing a cronjob that would run every minute and I put my computer to sleep and it didn't run, so it cannot be directly cause by power nap as far as I can tell